# Begin Storyboard in a UserControl embedded from behind code in Parent.xaml.cs in Windows Phone Application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, user-controls, storyboard

I have a custom UserControl named `MyControl` which I have embedded in my Parent Page - `MainPage.xaml` as:

```
<Canvas xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Namespace">
            <src:MyControl/>
        </Canvas>
```

I'm trying to call the `Begin()` method of a Storyboard inside `MyControl` from my Parent (MainPage.xaml.cs) with the following code:

```
MyControl usercontrol = new MyControl();

void BeginStoryBoard(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        usercontrol.InitializeComponent();
        usercontrol.storyboard.Begin();            
    }
```

But as expected and highly sure that it wouldn't work - It didn't work. So how can I achieve this?
Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is incomplete.  No one will able to answer your question fully.

The problems I see is that you already declared the custom user control as a child of your `Canvas`

but for some odd reason you try to create the custom user control again at

```
MyControl usercontrol = new MyControl();
```

Why?  Your Canvas will already do this, but you will need to give it a x:Name, like so

```
<Canvas xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Namespace">
    <src:MyControl x:Name="myCC"/>
</Canvas>
```

If you create a new one in code-behind like you did ...of course it won't work.  You never added it to the Visual Tree, so how would it know where to render it?

Give it a x:Name, and call your animation like so:

```
myCC.storyboard.Begin();
```

If that doesn't work, then you programmed the storyboard incorrectly.

Comment: Hello Chubosaurus, could you please answer this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828755/what-is-the-best-way-to-achieve-a-diagonal-text-animation-using-storyboards-in-a

Comment: @NavikGoswami sure, give me a sec.  This kinda of stuff is pretty easy, but it has to be exact.