# What is the best way to achieve a diagonal text animation using storyboards in a Windows Phone Application?

Tags: rotation, storyboard, projection, blend, rendertransform

I would like to create a storyboard that animates two TextBlocks by sliding them from right and left in the center of the Screen. I have tried rotating the TextBlocks and using `Global Offset` and `Local Offset` properties of `Projection` in **Blend for Visual Studio** and also manually using Translate X and Translate Y properties of the `RenderTransform` at specific `Keyrames`.

The storyboard does kick off and appears perfect in Blend but when running on the actual device, the 
TextBlocks don't appear in the center of the screen - sometimes they're in the top-left corner, sometimes in the bottom left and sometimes I barely see the ends of the TextBlocks.

How can I make my TextBlocks retain their positions?

The animation looks like this -> http://share.bannersnack.com/F9C55FD9E8C/bxt5w58pg

I would like them to look something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remember to define your `RenderTranform` and `CompositeTransform`

Then you can mess with the animation key values to achieve what you want.

I used a Rotation to achieve the diag, and 2 easing animation to achieved the slide, and a color animation to achieved your fading.  All you have to do is change the duration of the animation and the ending values to achieve what you want.

```XAML
<TextBlock x:Name="textbox1" Text="Super Awesome Diag Text" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Margin="0,200,0,0" >
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform Rotation="330"/>                    
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>         
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="textbox1">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0" />
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="textbox1">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-200"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="100" />
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="textbox1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).Color" From="Transparent" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>                    
    </TextBlock.Triggers>               
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Hello again Chubosaurus, sorry to hijack you here again. But could you please have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/42431825